# Bokeh Plot with equal axes

Tags: python, axes, bokeh

## Bokeh Plot with equal axes

I created a Plot with the `Python` library `Bokeh` (see code).

```
from bokeh.plotting import *

figure()
hold()
rect([1,3], [1,1], [1,0.5], [1,0.5])
patch([0,0,4,4], [2,0,0,2], line_color="black", fill_color=None)
show()
```

How can I represent the squares (rectangle with the same width and height) with equal axes as in matplotlib with the command `axis('equal')`?

http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/axis_equal_demo.html

I see the option to change the width and height of the plot or define the axis range to solve this problem but I think, there should be a smarter alternative.

NOTE: I'm using `Python v.2.7.8` and `Bokeh v.0.6.1`.

Comment: This is an open issue: https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/474

Comment: Thanks for the link. I am looking forward to use a solution.

Comment: Please note new answer by @DuCorey below regarding `match_aspect` in 0.12.7

Answer (score 23):

As of Bokeh 0.12.7, this feature has been implemented. Plots can now accept two new properties. 
`match_aspect` which, when set to true, will match the aspect of the data space to the pixel space of the plot. For example, squares drawn in data units will now be perfect squares in pixel units as well.

```
p = figure(match_aspect=True)
p.circle([-1, +1, +1, -1], [-1, -1, +1, +1])
```

[image: Bokeh match aspect = True]

`aspect_scale` allows you to further control the aspect ratio by specifying a multiplier on top of the aspect correction made by `match_aspect`.

```
p = figure(aspect_scale=2)
p.circle([-1, +1, +1, -1], [-1, -1, +1, +1])
```

[image: Bokeh aspect scale = 2]

```
p = figure(aspect_scale=0.5)
p.circle([-1, +1, +1, -1], [-1, -1, +1, +1])
```

[image: Bokeh aspect scale = 0.5]

Comment: It'd be instructive if you add the code used to generate these figures.

Comment: @jorgeh Thanks for the comment. I've added the code that was used to generate the figures.

Answer (score 4):

Sadly it seems that two years later this feature is still missing. As a workaround, I have written a function that sets the `x_range` and `y_range` properties of a figure appropriately to display your data with a given aspect ratio. This works fine as long as you don't allow any tools like box zoom that let the user modify the aspect ratio.

```
__all__ = ['set_aspect']

from bokeh.models import Range1d

def set_aspect(fig, x, y, aspect=1, margin=0.1):
    """Set the plot ranges to achieve a given aspect ratio.

    Args:
      fig (bokeh Figure): The figure object to modify.
      x (iterable): The x-coordinates of the displayed data.
      y (iterable): The y-coordinates of the displayed data.
      aspect (float, optional): The desired aspect ratio. Defaults to 1.
        Values larger than 1 mean the plot is squeezed horizontally.
      margin (float, optional): The margin to add for glyphs (as a fraction
        of the total plot range). Defaults to 0.1
    """
    xmin = min(xi for xi in x)
    xmax = max(xi for xi in x)
    ymin = min(yi for yi in y)
    ymax = max(yi for yi in y)
    width = (xmax - xmin)*(1+2*margin)
    if width <= 0:
        width = 1.0
    height = (ymax - ymin)*(1+2*margin)
    if height <= 0:
        height = 1.0
    xcenter = 0.5*(xmax + xmin)
    ycenter = 0.5*(ymax + ymin)
    r = aspect*(fig.plot_width/fig.plot_height)
    if width < r*height:
        width = r*height
    else:
        height = width/r
    fig.x_range = Range1d(xcenter-0.5*width, xcenter+0.5*width)
    fig.y_range = Range1d(ycenter-0.5*height, ycenter+0.5*height)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show

    x = [-1, +1, +1, -1]
    y = [-1, -1, +1, +1]
    output_file("bokeh_aspect.html")
    p = figure(plot_width=400, plot_height=300, tools='pan,wheel_zoom',
               title="Aspect Demo")
    set_aspect(p, x, y, aspect=2)
    p.circle(x, y, size=10)
    show(p)
```

Comment: FYI box zoom can now (as of `0.12` dev builds) be configured to respect the existing aspect of the plot.

Comment: Regarding the time frame, for a library that generates static images, aspect control would be a trivial feature. Unfortunately, Bokeh embeds plots in a larger browser layout context, and trying to reconcile fixed aspect with "web responsiveness" (also a continuously requested feature), it becomes a very thorny problem. We are working on it, as best and as fast as our limited resources permit.

Comment: This solution is great. However when implementing it to run on a 0.12.5 server, I had to instead modify the range start and end properties directly for it to work. 
`fig.x_range.start = xcenter - 0.5 * width
    fig.x_range.end = xcenter + 0.5 * width
    fig.y_range.start = ycenter - 0.5 * height
    fig.y_range.end = ycenter + 0.5 * height`

Comment: Please note new answer by @DuCorey below about `match_aspect` in 0.12.7